# An extension of Erdos' distinct distances problem based on circles of various radii

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

Consider a collection $C_1,C_2, \dots, C_n$ of circles in the plane and suppose that the center of $C_i$ is $o_i$ and the radius of $C_i$ is $r_i$. We will define the relative distance between the circles $C_i$ and $C_j$ as $$\frac {d(o_1,o_2)}{r_1+r_2},$$
where $d(x,y)$ is the Euclidean distance. So the relative distance is $\le 1$ if the two circles are intersecting, and $\ge 1$ if they are non overlapping.

What is the smallest possible number of distinct relative distances?

For unit circles this is Erdos' distinct distances problem that was famously settled by Guth and Katz.

Comment: Are you ranging over choices of $r_i$ or are the $r_i$ part of the input to the question?

Comment: Dear @SamHopkins, The "smallest possible number" is a function of $n$ and the input is an arbitrary collections of $n$ circuits. (Each circuit is determined by its center and radius.)

Comment: I am not sure that the relative distance is the most appropriate measure to take. Another option would be to take the cross ratio between the four points $o_i, x_{ij}, y_{ij},o_j$ where $x_{ij}$ and $y_{ij}$ are the intersections of the line segment $[o_i,o_j]$ with $C_i$ and $C_j$ respectively.

Comment: Do you also want to specify that the centres are distinct? Or else the answer is trivially 1, taking a collection of circles with the same centre and different radii.

Comment: Dear @ThomasBloom, yes we need to assume that.

Comment: Do you have an example when it can be less than for points? https://oeis.org/A186704

Comment: Dear @domotorp  No. On the other hand I didn't even proved that the number of distinct relative distances is >1 if n>3 (and in d-dimensions if n<d+1).

Comment: @domotorp,  Oops sorry we do have 4 (pairwise tangent) circles in the plane of relative distance 1. I dont know if other relative distances allow more.  So it is less than for points.